# How to solve the error : code can't be run by the observer

Tags: netlogo

While running the following code :

```
to modify
  let elements n-values 7 [(list)]
  ask turtles [
  let a item leader elements
    set a lput (who + 1) a
    set elements replace-item leader elements a 
]
  let CS []
  let prevCS CS
  set CS 0

  foreach elements [
show elements  
print ("elements")     
    if length ? > 0 [
    set S lput (sort ?) S
      set CS CS + getValue (sort ?)
      ]
  ]
end
```

I am getting error as :

```
this code can't be run by the observer
error while observer running IF
```

on the line :

`if length ? > 0`

I have no idea how to correct the error , any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using an older version of NetLogo? The ? syntax has been superseded. That's going to make it difficult for us to help because we can't test any of the code

Comment: I am modelling in Netlogo 5.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Poushan,

As JenB suggests, you really should upgrade to NetLogo 6.1.1.  Version 5.3.1 is no longer supported and it will be harder and harder for others to answer your questions.

That said, let me speculate on an answer.  In the code segment

```
 if length ? > 0 [
  set S lput (sort ?) S
  set CS CS + getValue (sort ?)
 ]
```

you refer to the variable `S` and the procedure `getValue`.  `S` is not defined in `to modify`, so it must be either a global, which should be okay, or a turtles-own variable, which is not okay.  The observer does not have direct access to it.  Similarly, `getValue` may be designed to be run by a turtle rather than the observer, and that would also give you the same error.

Hope this helps,
Charles